# Verify that users are required to change their password on their first login

Tags: active-directory, password

Active Directory has a setting that forces a user to change his password upon his next login--visible in the AD Users and Computers applet, when right-clicking a user, selecting Properties, then Account...the very first checkbox in the "Account options" list is labeled "User must change password at next login".

This is not quite what I'm after.  I've been tasked to find a way to make sure new AD users are forced to change their password during their first login (as in, the very first time they log in, ever).  Is there such a policy?  Ideally, I need something that works with Server 2003 domains and above.

Actually, that's not the full story...assuming such a policy exists, what I need to do is write a script that *verifies* that this is how the policy has been configured (that is, confirm that all new users *will* have to go through the process of getting their passwords changed).

Comment: The tickbox is automatically unticked after the first login. All you have to do is tick it after you create the user. As for verifying that this works, the only thing it involves is actually doing it.

Comment: gparent, that's exactly the problem with the existing approach; an admin might create a new user account, but untick the checkmark for one reason or another.  In an environment that's going to be scrutinized and audited by a third-party, I need to be able to show / make the assertion that this can never happen.  Not sure if that distinction makes sense...?

Comment: Then you need to prevent administrators from creating users directly and instead give them access to an API that does not allow them to do that.

Comment: In other words, it sounds like there's no built-in way to have AD enforce such a rule, as I then would need to make sure this custom API is in place.

Comment: Seems to me like you might be overthinking this.  Set the user's password to something, then come along after they log in and verify that the password is no longer the something it was originally created as.  That's a pretty easy script to write too, as a bonus.

Comment: That would assume I have access to the plaintext password (or a hash of it) to make the comparison.

Comment: You do, since you're creating the account.

Comment: I don't have access to the user's new password (or its hash) to make the comparison.  Besides, no, I'm not the one creating the account--I'm just playing the role of the guy running the audit.

Comment: You can use the script here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/get-password-reset-info-for-users-with-windows-powershell-script/ to basically report on user accounts.  But even if you added logic to pull the creation date of the user you'd need it down to the minute for both results to compare properly if you create the account in the morning and they change their password that day.  I agree with Gparent and Hopeless though....and when you create a user just leave the checkmark checked.  Simple IT policy.  If your IT admins can't follow it...get new ones.

Comment: Think of it from the perspective of a third-party auditor.  You're in no position to vouch for the admins in charge of those systems.  But you still need to look at the state of AD at a given point in time.  Granted, an admin can reconfigure AD (and re-open holes) the moment you walk out the door, but at least if you can generate a report that shows how it was configured while you were there and collected the state data, it's better than nothing.  Besides, AD can generate *some* events when it (itself) gets reconfigured--I'm assuming...I haven't yet started digging into that area.

Comment: @user275293 Well, in that case, I would advise you that auditors have the reputation they have in the IT community for a very good reason.  There's no good reason to care at all whether or not you can independently verify that a user's password has been changed since it was created. The only things you should care about is how difficult it is to compromise (the poor proxy that's in standard use for this is password complexity) and how many people know the password. Have concerns about whether or not it's been changed?  Tick the damn box to make them change it at next login, problem solved.

Comment: i have *exactly* the same issue, for the same reasons (independent auditor request), and this is literally the only discussion I've found about it. @user77560 did you ever resolve this? (I know this is 3 years old at the time I'm posting this comment)

Comment: JDS:  See my answer below.  Apparently I can't paste the whole thing as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is being asked here is for a technical security control where currently only an administrative security control exists - a technical enforcement of the existing policy in place that tells admins the change password at next logon box must be checked when creating new users.

The way to do this is with a custom password filter DLL for AD. A password filter is notified when there has been a change to a user password and can take any action required from there. Usually this is used for password sync applications (eg. Syncing AD passwords to Google Apps).

In this case the action would be something like detecting the age of the user account, if less than X minutes then check the change password flag on the user account, if not set then set the flag on the account, therefore removing the admins' ability to not set this flag, intentionally or otherwise.

Custom password filters are [described on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882(v=vs.85).aspx), and there is an [existing DLL called Password Hook](http://sourceforge.net/projects/passwdhk/) that already does the hard part of what you need - detect a password change and start a program / script specified in a registry key.

Comment: Interesting stuff, jotap.  Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of being able to install any binaries on any system; the best I'm allowed to do essentially is get in, run a script, get out.  I'll be discussing the feasibility with The Powers That Be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JDS:  This is the script I ended up with.  You can google some of the magic numbers - I forget the details.  Even though it's PowerShell, it should be pretty easy to translate to something else.  (Pardon the formatting, *something*'s having problems with it):

function Get-PwdLastSetValuesOfNeverLoggedInButEnabledAccounts()
{
    $root = [ADSI]""

```
# Search criteria:  Enabled accounts that have never logged in
$search = [ADSISearcher]$root            
$search.Filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=user)" + `
    "(!(useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" + `
    "(logoncount:=0)" + `
    ")"
$search.SizeLimit = 1500

$dictionary = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String, System.Int64]'
try
{
    $results = $search.FindAll()
}
catch [System.Exception]
{
    # Ignore (allow) "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"
    # (the machine is not on a domain at all)
    if ( $_.Exception.HResult -ne 0x8007054B )
    {
        $dictionary.Add( "ExceptionWasThrown", -1 )
    }
    return $dictionary
}

foreach ( $result in $results )
{
    Write-Host "User $($result.Properties[ "name" ]):  $($result.Properties[ "pwdlastset" ][ 0 ])"
    if ( $result.Properties[ "pwdlastset" ] -ne 0 )
    {
        # Ignore admin accounts ending with "$"
        if ( $result.Properties[ "name" ][ 0 ].EndsWith( "$" ) ) { continue; }

        $dictionary.Add( $result.Properties[ "name" ], $result.Properties[ "pwdlastset" ][ 0 ] )
    }
}

return $dictionary
```

}

$dictionary = Get-PwdLastSetValuesOfNeverLoggedInButEnabledAccounts